# Scraping a table from website that is dynamically loaded not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the contents from the table on this website
https://www.corelogic.com.au/our-data/recent-sales?postcode=3056

When I inspect the page I can see all the columns and rows in the html code but when I try to find the table using BeautifulSoup it comes up with "None"

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.corelogic.com.au/our-data/recent-sales?postcode=3056"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')
table = soup.find("table")
print(table)
```

*Output:* None

Comment: There is no table in the actual HTML source of the page; it is created dynamically. Please see the linked duplicate as this is an extremely commonly asked question.